# CiviCRM and Apache Solr - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, search

I have CiviCRm installed Drupal 7 and Apache Solr Api.

My search configuration says that the site is 100% indexed, however there are CiviCRM events that do not show up in a search. For example, we had an event in the past titled "Mom You're Incredible". A search for "mom" or "mom you're incredible" shows no results.

Does Apache Solr index CiviCRM data, or is there a special procedure that has to be completed. I have CiviCRM in a separate database (MySQL) as recommended on the CiviCRM site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache solr module by default does not index civicrm tables. There is an integration with this module that indexes civicrm attachments:

https://github.com/civicrm/apachesolr_civiAttachments

This was work done for the New York State Senate. The next steps would be to get other civicrm tables indexed via this or other similar modules.

You might want to check the [Drupal Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity)  integration. This might make integrating with solr a lot easier

If you do make progress on this, please do share your work